# Combine Two Complex SQL Queries Into One

Tags: mysql, sql

My mySQL database has a `schools` and a `users` table. Each school has an `id` that identifies it. When a user joins a school, the user's `school` column is set to the `id` of that school. I need to execute a request which does the following:

1. Gets a random school from the database that has users joined to it. (Must have at least one student in the database whose `school` column is set to that school's `id`.)
2. Gets the user at that school with the highest (successes / attempts) value.
3. If multiple users at the school are tied for the highest value, the query will select a random user and return it.

All I need in return is the user object. I know I could use PHP for some of the work, but I would like to do the majority in the SQL query. If possible, I would like to do this all in one request. Is this possible? So far I've come up with:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  `schools` 
INNER JOIN  `users` ON schools.id = users.school
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

at which point I could save the selected school's id in PHP as $schoolID and execute another request:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
WHERE school =2
AND attempts !=0
ORDER BY (
successes / attempts
) DESC , RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to combine them into one SQL query to save server load?

Structure:

Users Table:

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| username   | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| school     | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |                |
| successes  | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| attempts   | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Schools Table:

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sample Data:
Users table:

```
id  username    school  successes   attempts
1   josh        1       0           0
2   james       2       0           1
3   ashley      2       2           2
4   john        1       1           1
5   will        3       4           8
6   jack        3       1           2
```

Schools table:

```
id  name
1   school1
2   school2
3   school3 
4   school4
```

Only schools 1-3 should be able to be chosen from `schools`, and only user 4 should show if school 1 was chosen, user 3 should show if school 2 was chosen, and either user 5 or 6 should show if school 3 was chosen.

Comment: I think the explanation would be clearer if you provided sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have tried to simplify the desired results. If you still do not understand I can add some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revised again so that it will NOT retrieve all records in the inner query. Safe to use with larger data sets. The inner select gets a random school which has a valid user record. The outer select selects on that school record and sorts by success / attempts and limits to one. Tested with your data.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, users.username, users.successes, users.attempts 
FROM ((SELECT schools.id, schools.name from schools INNER JOIN users on schools.id = users.school
    WHERE users.attempts !=0
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1) s)
INNER JOIN users on s.id = users.school
ORDER BY users.successes / users.attempts DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I took down my answer until I could test further. This query should work. I will test with your structure and data as well.

Comment: If you include users.successes and users.attempts in the result, you will see that this does not work. It is returning a user with a lower max (users.successes / users.attempts) than the school's max.

Comment: With the data I have entered, it returns the max of successes / attempts (a decimal value). Are you sure you are looking at the school's max successes/attempts and not just max successes?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I have posted some sample data and the expected results. I have tried your query and while the max value returned is correct, it returns the wrong user (a user with a different max value). Edit: Perhaps you are misunderstanding the goal. I do not care for the actual max value, only for the user to which it belongs.

Comment: I have revised so that it will do as you wish. I could not figure out how to limit retrieving all records in the inner query. It will therefore pull all records in the search.

Comment: Revised again so that it will NOT retrieve all records in the inner query.